# gulp defining tasks with parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp

currently I'm building my gulp file. I want to parse my folder or file path as a parameter for my gulp task. by default it was ,

```
gulp.task('convert', function(){
    gulp.src('the path hard coded');
})
```

here I want to parse a the path as a parameter. I couldn't do it with above mentioned gulp task. therefore I wrote a function for that,

```
var convert = function(myPath){
   gulp.src(mypath)
    .pipe(); //etc
}
```

then I called this function like

```
 convert(myPath);
```

anywhere in the gulp file to call it. its working perfectly. I want to know will there be any bad effect when I use like this in my gulp file.

Comment: code is working :)